# I am getting a linker error when I trying to build a project

Tags: compiler-errors, embedded, linker-errors, segger-jlink

I am working on an embedded engineering project.

I am picking up the work someone else did, and I am quite confused with the error message I am getting when trying to build the project.

I looked online for similar problems but I do not find anything useful, and as I am quite new to Segger Embedded Studio I am struggling to diagnose the problem.

Here is the error message:

[image]

If someone can give me an idea to where to start looking toward it would be appreciated.

If there is information missing I will add it.

Comment: The `undefined reference` error tells you that the linker cannot find a reference to that symbol `nrf_log_backend_rtt_api`. This could be for multiple reasons. Can you get a symbol table from your compiler, this symbol should be listed. are your header files included correctly?

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for reaching out, how do i get the symbol table from the compiler?
For the header files they are included in the application folder. They are also called in the main function.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your toolchain but the file often has an extension `.map`. Do you have a complete `output` file from your compiler that you can share?

Comment: I do have a map file, i found it. What shoud l be looking for in that file?

Comment: Look for your missing symbol `nrf_log_backend_rtt_api`

Comment: I cannot find it in the map.. that's not a great sign

Comment: If it's not there, it wasn't compiled i.e. the linker cannot find it. Is it present in your source code, do you have a typo? Is it excluded due to pre-compiler directives? These are just a couple of reasons why it might be missing.

Comment: Maybe you're missing the include (of the file where the function is declared) in the source file where you're calling the function...?

Comment: The error means that there are old object files present not necessarily corresponding to the current state of the source. Pick Build -> Clean project name, then build again. You shouldn't add object files to your version control.

Comment: @stdcerr An error "undefined reference" has nothing to do with compiling or including header files. It is clearly a linker message, and so the implementing object file or library is missing.

Comment: @Lundin I cleared the project and rebuilt it again, but I got the same issue...

Comment: @thebusybee so I need to make sure that the nrf_log_backend_rtt_api library is within the project file? Or maybe im not understanding...

Comment: Are these files located in a sub directory?

Comment: These files nrf_log_backend_rtt_api ?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? What was the problem?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get time to resolve it, I will work on it tonight @stdcerr, I will update you on where i get tonight.

Comment: I saw that in my config file the following : 
#ifndef nrf_log_backend_rtt Enabled 
#define nrf_log_backend_rtt Enabled 1 
#endif
and I changed it to 
#ifndef nrf_log_backend_rtt Enabled 
#define nrf_log_backend_rtt Enabled 0
#endif
my code complied.. i do not know what i was doing wrong, would be great if someone can explain it.